# Reactive form issue

Tags: angular, forms

I'm trying to follow the guide in https://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/ to learn to build a reactive form, but it doesn't seem to be working. Per now i have this html code:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="click == false">
    <p>For bestilling fyll ut skjemaet <button (click)="showForm()" mat-raised-button color="primary">her</button></p>
</ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="click == true">
    <section class="sample-app-content">
        <h1>Reactive Form Example:</h1>
        <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <p>
                <label>First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="password" formControlName="password">
            </p>
            <p>
                <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
            </p>
        </form>
    </section>
</ng-template>
```

TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } 
    from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hotel',
  templateUrl: './hotel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hotel.component.scss']
})
export class HotelComponent {
  click:boolean = false

  showForm = () => {
    this.click = true
  }


  form = fb.group({
    "firstName": ["", Validators.required],
    "password": ["", Validators.required]
  });

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log("reactive form submitted");
    console.log(this.form);
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './index/index.component';
import { HotelComponent } from './hotel/hotel.component';
import { QuizComponent } from './quiz/quiz.component';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    IndexComponent,
    HotelComponent,
    QuizComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But i just get this error:
src/app/hotel/hotel.component.ts:18:10 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'fb'.

18   form = fb.group({

Comment: Try changing this `constructor(fb: FormBuilder)` to this `constructor(private fb: FormBuilder)`.

Comment: What R.richards said (looks like a mistake in that tutorial). Also, your ngIf’s look strange. Should be *ngIf

Comment: @MikeOne You can bind that way if you want: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#selectors

Comment: Yes, but why would you? Especially as a beginner I wouldn’t touch this.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `private` in the injector and you're missing `this` before `fb`. [This is a much better guide](https://fireship.io/lessons/basics-reactive-forms-in-angular/) to reactive forms, by the way.

```js
  form = this.fb.group({
    "firstName": ["", Validators.required],
    "password": ["", Validators.required]
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }
```

Comment: The mentioned tutorial uses the way which makes you lose typed forms benefit (everthing is any)